# Authentication with TFS 2017 vs 2013

Tags: migration, team-foundation-server

I just migrated to TFS 2017 from 2013.  Since the server is running on a domain-joined machine, I would login using DOMAIN\Username - however, with 2017 it won't let me put in the domain when I login - it only works when only the Username is specified.

What am I missing?  Shouldn't our users need to put in their domain to authenticate?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the error/validation and the auth dialog?

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2017 requires Kerberos now so you probably need to make sure the service accounts are setup for that https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2017/01/24/team-foundation-server-2017-and-kerberos-authentication/